# Linear homogeneous recursive sequence of constant sign

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Let recursive sequence be defined by the formula 
$$
s_{j+1}=as_j-s_{j-1},
$$
where $a>1$ is some integer number. Is it true that $s_0<0$, $s_1<0$ implies $s_j<0$ for $j \geq 0$?

**Edit:** No, its wrong. Under what conditions on $s_0$ and $s_1$ property $s_j<0$ holds?

Comment: $s_0=-42$, $s_1=-17$, $a=2$.

Comment: Nope. consider the case $a = 2, s_0 = -2, s_1 = -1$, you will find $s_2 = 0$ and in general $s_n = n - 2$.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assume $a > 2$, the characteristic equation of the recurrence equation
$$s_{j+1} = a s_{j} - s_{j-1}$$

is given by
$$\lambda^2 - a \lambda + 1 = 0$$
It has roots at $\mu$ and $\mu^{-1}$ where $\displaystyle \mu = \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2-4}}{2} > 1$.
The general solution of the recurrence equation have the form

$$s_j = A \mu^j + B \mu^{-j}$$

Solving $A$ and $B$ from $s_0$ and $s_1$, we get:

$$s_j = \frac{\mu s_1 - s_0}{\mu^2 - 1}\mu^j + \frac{\mu^2 s_0 - \mu s_1}{\mu^2 - 1} \mu^{-j}$$

Since $|\mu| > 1 > |\mu^{-1}|$, $s_j$ will be dominated by the term $A \mu^j$ for large $j$. If $A > 0$,
then $s_j$ will be positive for sufficient large $j$. This means $A \le 0$ is an necessary
condition for all $s_j < 0$. This condition is also sufficient. If $A \le 0$, then for $j > 1$, we have

$$s_j = A \mu^j + B \mu^{-j} = A \mu ( \mu^{j-1} - \mu^{1-j} ) + \mu^{1-j} (A \mu + B \mu^{-1})\\ = A \mu ( \mu^{j-1} - \mu^{1-j} ) + \mu^{1-j} s_1 \le \mu^{1-j} s_1 < 0$$

Conclusion, the necessary and sufficient condition for all $s_j < 0$ is $A \le 0 \iff \mu s_1 - s_0 \le 0$.

For $a = 2$, the general solution has the form

$$s_j = A j + B$$

It is easy to see the necessary and sufficient condition is again $A \le 0 \iff s_1 - s_0 \le 0$.